# jQuery auto select first link

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery function that shows / hides content depending on the link that is clicked..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('div.col-md-4').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    var selector = '#div' + jQuery(this).data('target');
    jQuery(selector).show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7954/

To avoid having no content display when the page first loads I am trying to have it automatically select the first link.

Does anybody have an example or can point me in the direction of some reading on which function I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, just find the element you wish to click. Then use `.click()`  function of jQuery like this:

```
  jQuery('.showSingle').first().click();
```

So I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ebd6nym/